# how to onnx convert and connect openvino

Tags: keras, onnx, openvino

I want to do inference using openvino.
But I got an error while using openvino.
Any way to solve it?`enter code here`

```
model = keras.models.load_model('/resnet50.h5')
onnx_model, _ = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model, opset=16)
onnx.save(onnx_model, '/t1_model.onnx')

ie = IECore()

net = ie.read_network("/t1_model.onnx")
input_name = list(net.input_info.keys())[0]
output_name = list(net.outputs.keys())[0]

net.input_info[input_name].precision = 'FP32'
net.outputs[output_name].precision = 'FP32'

exec_net = ie.load_network(network=net, device_name='CPU')
```

I faced these problems.

```
RuntimeError: Check 'std::get<0>(valid)' failed at C:\j\workspace\private-ci\ie\build-windows-vs2019@3\b\repos\openvino\src\inference\src\ie_core.cpp:1414:
InferenceEngine::Core::LoadNetwork doesn't support inputs having dynamic shapes. Use ov::Core::compile_model API instead. Dynamic inputs are :{ input:'input_1,input_1', shape={?,256,256,3}}
```

input_shape = (None, 256,256,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IECore API doesn't support dynamic shapes so you need to make your model static before you load it into the plugin. You can use the `reshape()` method on the imported model.

As an alternative you can switch to the 2022.1 version of OV where the dynamic shapes are supported. You have to switch from `IECore` to `Core`, `read_network` -> `read_model`, `load_network` -> `compile_model`.

Comment: To answer, after model_load works, I modify it to model.input.set_shape((1,256,256,3)) and it works Thank you.